# PHP Display hours until a certain event from a time given

Tags: php, mysql, time

So basically, What I wanted to happen was, I wanted to submit an article which submits my current time() and the amount of hours until a certain event. I wished for it to calculate the amount of time in hours from the time() in the database to the amount of hours since that article was posted.
So if I posted an article for an event happening at 3pm, and the current time is 12pm, It would say "Event in 3 hours". And if I were to check again at 2pm, It would say "Event in 1 hours". 
Sorry if this seems like a noob question, But I am quite the stupid person when it comes to maths and stuff.
Thanks in advance for any input, I appreciate it!

Comment: How are you saving your dates/times in the database?

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you store the time of the article as a timestamp, and you retrieve the value in the variable $articleTime:

```
$hoursLeft = floor(($articleTime - time()) / 3600);
```